# Magento 2 require.js problem on checkout page with MultiSafePay plugin

Tags: checkout, requirejs

I installed [MultiSafePay Connect plugin](https://www.multisafepay.com/nl_nl/oplossingen/shop-plug-ins/detail/plugins/magento-2-1/). But when I add a product to the shopping basket and go to checkout. I see some errors in the console (see attachments). But I think all required files ar on the server.

[image]

Whats happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it´s saying that the .js-files could not be found in the pub/static... directory. Most of the other errors just refer to that.

Just make sure you run 
`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL` in the console in the magento installation directory. This should copy all static files (incuding your .js-files into the pub/static..directories.

Then this error will disapear.